# Static factory method vs public constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, static-factory

**Background:**

Here's the code for what I'm currently working on. First, the base class, which is an account class that holds information about the account and has some methods that for the most part change the values of the class's properties.

```
public class Account {
    private string _username; [...]

    public string Username { get { return _username; } } [...]

    public Account() { }

    public Account(string[] args) { [...] }

    public virtual void ChangePassword(string newPassword) { [...] }
}
```

Then, I have another class for when the account has been created, which I have named ActiveAccount. This contains most of the logic for the actions I want to use for the account that are only possible once the account has been created. Some classes need not to be included to explain the question; use your imagination to assume what those classes may do:

```
public class ActiveAccount : Account
{
    private List<Conversation> _conversations; [...]

    public List<Conversation> Conversations { get { return _conversations; } } [...]

    private ActiveAccount() { }

    public static ActiveAccount CreateAccount(Account account)
    {
        // Navigate to URL, input fields, create account, etc.
    }

    public override void ChangePassword(string newPassword)
    {
        // Navigate to URL, input fields, change password, etc.

        // Update property using base method, if no errors.
        base.ChangePassword(newPassword);
    }
}
```

I've used a static factory method for two reasons. 1) I want customiseable and extensible construction of an object (for example, in the future I might have an AccountTemplate from which I provide generic information to create accounts; I can easily create another static factory method overload with an AccountTemplate parameter), and 2) having a parameterless constructor allows me to serialize this object more easily into XML/JSON.

**Question:**

However, it's come to my attention that I could just as easily have a public constructor that accepts an Account parameter, performs the logic and can be extended with overloads just as easily. I can keep my private parameterless constructor to prevent parameterless construction and allow serialization.

I'm quite new to programming. What I'm wondering is if there is a specific reason to use static factory methods instead of public constructors, as explained above. And what's the preferred way of doing what I want to do?

Comment: 10 years and how are you now? What is your point of view now about this Factory pattern use case? @nick

Comment: Ha wow, this is an old question! I'd recommend not using a static method on the instance, and instead having an abstract method on a separate `AccountFactory` that accepts settings e.g., `accountFactory.create(IAccountSettings)`. I guess I'd prefer an instance method, if the factory required some configuration itself (e.g.,`new AccountFactory(IDatabase)`). I'd use the constructor if I wanted `Account` instances to be responsible for their own creation, but factories help e.g., centralize creation configuration, instead of having to pass that every time. Thanks for the nostalgia!

Comment: A reason for preferring the factory with an interface could be that the abstract factory can implement to an interface. E.g., `create(settings: IAccountSettings} { ... this.database.save(...) }`, where `this.database: IDatabase`. If you know that regardless of what type of account the factory makes that you'll need to save the account entity, the contract with the database allows you to inject the specific database type at factory creation time, and now the factory works with databases of any kind that meet your contract

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I wouldn't call what you used a static factory. In my eyes it's a "named constructor" since it resides in the class itself and just creates an object of that particular class.

It is often used to make the operation easier to understand, e.g. compare

```
int value = Int32.Parse(someString);
int value = new Int32(someString); // doesn't really exist
```

The first version makes it clear that it parses the input string, the second is far less verbose.

**Update:** one important difference between constructors and static methods like `Int32.Parse` is that static methods can chose whether to return `null` in case an error occured or throw an exception. A constructor can only throw an exception or - and I wouldn't recommend that - leave the object in some sort of limbo state where it is only half-initialized.

---

A static factory is used to decouple classes, and to make it easier to change the implementation, for example instead of instantiating a database connection using the `new` operator in your code every time you need a database connection you use a factory method that returns an interface:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
IDbConnection myConnection = myFactory.CreateConnection();
```

The advantage is that by simply changing the `CreateConnection` method you can make global changes to your entire project, swapping databases servers or even database providers without having to change your code in all the places where you actually use the database connection.

Comment: I really like this explanation. I do feel that it is more clear to have a named constructor in this case, question solved!

Comment: @NickBull Thanks, also read the [.NET constructor guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229060%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that Ondrej posted in his answer. They can be very useful.

Answer (score 17):

I would advise you to read the [.NET constructor guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229060%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). There are some points that probably leads to choosing a static factory instead of a constructor in your case. Namely

> Do minimal work in the constructor. Constructors should not do much work other than to capture the constructor parameters. The cost of any other processing should be delayed until required.

and

> Consider using a static factory method instead of a constructor if the semantics of the desired operation do not map directly to the construction of a new instance, or if following the constructor design guidelines feels unnatural.

Answer (score 0):

There are my consideration about when you need to prefer a static factory method and when a constructor.

1) Use a static factory method if you need to do some additional actions/initializations that cannot be done by a constructor.
For example if you need to publish newly created `ActiveAccount` object (e.g. `SomePublicList.Add(ActiveAccount);` ) then it's a bad practice to publish it from within it's own constructor.

2) Think about inheritance. If you need to create a descendent class (e.g. `NewActiveAccout`) for `ActiveAccount` then you need to provide a non-private constructor in `ActiveAccount`. Perhaps you need to prefer a constructor to a factory method in that case.

3) If you need to pass some parameters to the base class (`Account`) constructor then you need to implement a constructor in `ActiveAccount` because you can't pass parameters to base class constructor from a static factory method.

Comment: With regard to #2, is there any reason the constructor would need to be public rather than protected?  To my mind, the set of ways to produce a given type should be independent from the set of ways to produce derivatives (the fact that `Foo` allows everyone to use a particular constructor to produce `Foo` instances doesn't mean that everyone should be allowed to derive from `Foo`, and the fact that a constructor may be usable by derivatives of `Foo` doesn't mean it should be usable to create instances of type `Foo` itself).

Comment: @supercat In my opinion, if a class already has a constructor needed by derived classes then in many cases there is no reason to implement a static factory method with absolutely the same functionality. Moreover I think that object construction/initialization should be considered uniformly in both cases when an object is constructed as a stand-alone object or as a part of an object of derived class. In both cases an object has to be correctly constructed/initialized. And usually the constructor paradigm perfectly serves the both cases as a single point of object construction/initialization.

Comment: If `String` didn't have public constructors, it could have made sense to have a few types derived from `String` (e.g. `AsciiString`, `Ucs2String`, `FullUnicodeString`, etc.), all of which would know how to interact with each other [since the vast majority of strings contain only character codes 0-127, storing them in a packed format could save considerable space and time].  Since .NET has not been designed that way, a lot of code has been written that would break with such a design, but if it were understood from the start that `String` could have many representations...

Comment: ...it would not have posed any particular difficulty for client code.  The existence of any public constructor, however, would have made it impossible to restrict the instantiation of derivative types to the assembly that defined `String` (a `String` class which would allow two people, neither who knows of each other's existence, to write derivatives of `String` which can interact would have to be much more complicated than one where each subtype has a fixed set of other subtypes it must work with).